# my stylesheet is not working using CSS bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-specificity

I am just learning how to do a basic web page. So this is the main code

```
<navbar class="navbar navbar-light pip-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      HP 90/90
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      LEVEL 1
      <div class="level-progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      AP 50/50
    </div>
  </div>
</navbar>
```

then I want to apply these measures so that the words are spaced, but as you can see in the image they don't move

```
.pip-footer{ position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;}
```

[here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YzcJ.png)

[should be look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Afs.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to bootstrap website here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
you can change the classes to be like

```
 <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
```

another solution which is I don't know if it still works in bootstrap4 is that you can wrap all you divs that contain `col` class inside a `div` the have `col-12` class so the code will be

```
<navbar class="navbar navbar-light pip-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-3">
        HP 90/90
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        LEVEL 1
        <div class="level-progress"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        AP 50/50
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely a matter of the bootstrap classes' selectors having a higher *specifity*. In general you should be careful with this, but you can add `!important` to a setting to override more specific selectors, like in your case `position: fixed !important;` (and similar for the other parameters if necessary)